# Segue passing data but not animating the ViewController presentation

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have this problem:
I have two ViewControllers.
I am transitioning to the second view with Segue.
User enters his name on first view controller and taps on a button. If the text is nil, it should not show the second view controller. If some text is there on the text field - it has to show the next view controller.

I am checking the text length here below. As I have only one segue... I am not checking  segue identifier.

And, on Storyboard, I have give modal transition CoverVertical. The animation is not working. View is just appearing.  UIModalTransitionStyle also I tried. Still not working (on device and simulator)

```
-(BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
    if(playerNameTextField.text.length == 0)
    {
        UIColor *tempColor=UIColorFromRGB(0xFF4981);
        [self colorizeTextViewForAWhile:playerNameTextField withUIColor:tempColor animated:YES];
        return NO;
    }    
    return YES;
}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueMoveToHome"])
    {
        ViewController *vc = (ViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.playerName=playerNameTextField.text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:` and single stepped? Check that `playerNameTextField` is not nil - if it is you may have forgotten to bind the IBOutlet in IB

Comment: Yes. Yes. I put breakpoint. Everything is perfect except the transition animation. and transition flag I gave YES.

Comment: Ok.  Perhaps you could clarify your question. Your title implies that the second view isn't showing, but it seems that the issue is that the transition isn't animating?

Comment: in Storyboard, did you check that the `animates` checkbox is checked? I'm talking about the segue

Comment: I have removed the Identifier text and continued. As it was the only segue or any other reason... it was working. If I put the segue... it is not working.  :| Not sure. But I have now my app working.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly. I just reproduced and I've got a transition with CoverVertical.

In Interface Builder, select the Storyboard Segue and be sure that you have:

[image]

I'm [linking](https://copy.com/yrkWYUVC3dTsBjEO) you a mini demo with your code that works.

Comment: Thank you Gabe. I have removed the Identifier text and continued. As it was the only segue or any other reason... it was working. If I put the segue... it is not working.  :| Not sure. But I have now my app working.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the Identifier text and continued. As it was the only segue or any other reason... it was working. If I put the segue... it is not working.  :| Not sure. But I have now my app working.